TStringGrid ColumnBackground weird behaviour
I want to change cells background of the 4 first columns depending on the color name in the 9th column (or record value if possible, but i didn't manage to make it work).
procedure TDataGrid.OnDrawColumnBackground(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn;
  const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  RowColor : TBrush;
begin
  if Column.Index < 4 then
  begin
    RowColor := Tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColors.Alpha);
    RowColor.Color := System.UIConsts.StringToAlphaColor(TStringGrid(Sender).Cells[9, TStringGrid(Sender).Row]);
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, RowColor);
    TStringGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawing := true; 
  end;
end;

The behaviour is really weird.
When I open my form, I get this:

When I go row by row down with the keyboard:

It's coloring the line with the next color
Or when I click on the line it shows the color on the line I clicked or in the mouse position!

And the worst is when I scroll down it make all the rows colored in one color again, like if I just opened the form again.
Does anyone have an idea on how to make it work?

Why do you need the current logic, where you change the color with the keyboards button? Don't you need to have it colored as soon as it opens?

Is it supposed to work the way you want?  Perhaps it's called OnDrawColumnBackground for a reason, i.e. it is designed to colour the entire column (but only updates the background for individual cells that it changes).  Have you tried OnDrawColumnCell (although that also has Column in the name)?

@ineffable21 : i use the OnDrawColumnBackGround which is called when need to draw the background of a cell in a specified column. I never code it when the keyboard is pressed ! that's the problem.

@PhilipJ.Rayment : if i use OnDrawColumCell, it means i must draw on my own the cell from background to text and so on. But i use ColumnStyle that already manage drawing of the content. (StringColumn  CheckColumn CurrencyColumn DateColumn DateTimeColumn FloatColumn, GlyphColumn IntegerColumn PopupColumn ProgressColumn  TimeColumn). I would like to avoid rewrite something that work fine. Or maybe there is a way to draw only the background and let the StringGrid do the rest of the job ?

@ffert2907: "Or maybe there is a way to draw only the background and let the StringGrid do the rest of the job ?"  There is.  See my answer.

Use OnDrawColumnCell() instead, to draw the background, then call DefaultDrawCell to draw the contents:
procedure TForm1.TDataGridDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  RowColor : TBrush;
begin
  if Column.Index < 4 then
  begin
    RowColor := Tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColors.Alpha);
    RowColor.Color := System.UIConsts.StringToAlphaColor(TStringGrid(Sender).Cells[9, TStringGrid(Sender).Row]);
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, RowColor);
  end;
  Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas,Bounds,Row,Value,State);
end;


I tried your solution, but it's doing exaclty the same error than before with DrawColumnBackground. Only one color is showed at start (the one on the first row). When i click on a row it shows the right color of the row...

And also, i lost the images...
